# Integration Rasa chatwoot with Chatwoot Application

Tags: integration, rasa, handoff, chatwoot

I'm currently working on integrating Rasa and Chatwoot, following the documentation provided. However, I've encountered an issue where requests from Chatwoot to Rasa are not reaching my Rasa application. I'm running both applications locally for testing purposes.

Document1 : https://www.chatwoot.com/docs/product/others/agent-bots
demo :https://github.com/chatwoot/rasa-agent-bot-demo

Here's what I've done so far:

- I have a local instance of Rasa running on `http://localhost:5005`.
- My Chatwoot instance is running locally on `http://localhost:3000`.
- router.py in "localhost://8000"
- I've followed the integration steps outlined in the Chatwoot documentation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Xjy.png)

I've attempted to implement the architecture described above. While the initial request successfully reached the Chatwoot server, there seems to be an issue with the subsequent steps. Specifically, the agent is not receiving requests from Chatwoot.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue, especially with the agent bot in the mix, would be greatly appreciated.